# C# Trouble with leap year

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I have 3 combo-boxes define as: month, day, and year. I managed to populate all of them like specific days in a month ( March has 31 days, Feb has 28, April has 30,...). Well I'm having trouble with leap year. See my code below:

```
public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);
        for (int year = 1950; year <= DateTime.Today.Year; year++)
        {
            this.comboBox3.Items.Add(year.ToString());
            if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
            {
                if (comboBox1.Text == "February")
                {
                    {
                        int day;
                        for (day = 0; day < 29; day++)
                        {
                            comboBox2.Items.Add(day.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add(info.GetMonthName(i));
        }
    }

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int month = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        if (month >= 0)
        {
            month++;
            int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Date.Year, month);
            var range = Enumerable.Range(1, days);
            comboBox2.DataSource = range.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: What is your _trouble_ exactly? Can you please be more specific about it?

Comment: You don't really specify what problem you have. One thing that strikes me is that it looks like you print 0-28, when you should print 1-29.

Comment: i.e I choose 2012 which is a leap year, and choose february, the index for combobox day has only 28, which is wrong. it should be 29

Comment: Yeah, like I said, change your for-loop to:
`for (day = 1; day < 30; day++)`

Comment: @hellogoodnight omg i'm sorry bout that, i missed that i was about to use `<=`, thanks for pointing me.

Comment: @hellogoodnight still it doesn't work

Comment: Really? It gives you the same result as before?

Comment: do your for-loop look like this?:

`for(int day = 1; day <= 29; day++)`

Comment: @hellogoodnight yes same result as before and i tried using for (day = 1; day < 30; day++)

Comment: @Rom , ok well try to Clean Solution and Rebuild Solution and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the loading of the day to the combobox1 selectedindexchanged event

```
public void Form5()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);
    for (int year = 1950; year <= DateTime.Today.Year; year++)
        this.comboBox3.Items.Add(year.ToString());

    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add(info.GetMonthName(i));
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Sanity check...
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBox3.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select an year before!");
        return;
    }

    // Get the current selected year and use it in DaysInMonth
    int year = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text);

    int month = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    if (month >= 0)
    {
        combobox2.DataSource = null;

        month++;
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        var range = Enumerable.Range(1, days);
        comboBox2.DataSource = range.ToList();
    }
}
```

It is in that event that you could look at the information available in the Year combobox. Then use the year selected as input for the DateTime.DaysInMonth call. (Also do not forget to clear the previous DataSource for the day combo otherwise you will not see any change in the combo)

Finally a suggestion: Why don't you change the names of those combos to something more meaningful (IE: cboYears, cboMonths, cboDays), you will avoid a lot of confusion

Looking again to your scenario, I think you need also code in the comboBox3.SelectedINdexChanged. You need to reset the days combo also if you change the year

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     combobox2.DataSource = null;
     combobox2.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works. As far as i understand your code, the user should fill the combobox year first, right? Is there any way that the user should fill up the month first? It is the requirement of our instructor. I believe that he is not aware of this.

Comment: At form constructor you fill both year and month combos in whichever order you like. The day combo should be filled only when you know the year and the month. But when you change the year combo, then the day combo need to be reset (and eventually refilled with days looking at the current month selected) , the same with the month combo